# Why does gmail work on one iMac but not on another?

Tags: mac, gmail

I have two iMacs standing next to each other.  On one gmail keeps going down, with the message"Can't reach server".  On the other iMac gmail is fine.

This problem affects gmail only.  Other sites can be accessed OK.

And both iMacs are connected wirelessly to the same modem router.

Why is this happening? And how can it be corrected?

Comment: If I remember, Gmail leans pretty heavy on AJAX.  Is it possible that on one, that javascript is disabled, or set to timeout and not do background actions?

Comment: Are both using the same browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc), and same version?  Also, is the OSX version the same for both?